# Conversion of CMYK to RGB using U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2 color space

Tags: javascript, python, rgb, cmyk

I want to convert CMYK to RGB using javascript or python etc.

The conversion depends on the “Colorspace” that is being used in the CMYK system.   In our case, we use the Colorspace of:  U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2

So, the CMYK colors are different RGB codes for this colorspace, than they would be for another colorspace.

For example, when we open up Adobe Illustrator and put in the CMYK value, the RGB and Hex values are different from those in an online conversion screen that does not adjust for Colorspace.

I tried using Colorvert. It seems to work but can anyone provide exact solution/ snippet.

Comment: get the `icc` file of the SWOP v2 colour space, and the `icc` of the output space (e.g. sRGB: the "RGB" used by web). Then select a colour intent. But probably the gamut of CMYK will be smaller than of the output RGB so you do not need to worry much about it. Then just usual colour space convertion (using icc profiles)

Comment: Thanks, this process requires little cms. Its not on windows. Do you have other solution?